# How can I read the color of a specific pixel in XNA?

Tags: c#, colors, xna, coordinates, pixel

I want a way to find out if, for example, the pixel at Vector2(2, 5) on the game window is color Color.Red, or some other color or set of coordinates. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the same method as used in per pixel collision. That gets the color data of textures and loops through to check those pixels against another textures pixels. You will just have to change it a bit to get it so you can use a coordinate and get the specific color data. Basically the colors or stored in an array in a specific order. Then you just need to calculate the x and y position of the texture and the vector2 that you want to load the correct pixel. Also note that if you use scaled textures you will need to use a matrix to get the correct pixel.

Comment: I know how to get data from textures and such, but what I want to do is get the color of a specific pixel in the game window, not out of a texture.

Comment: You would have to find out all textures at that point. Then you can get the color from the texture as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Convert texture into array, and then based on coordinated find specified pixel and get color. Example can be found here on [Reimers XNA](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Texture_to_Colors.php) webpage.

```
private Color[,] TextureTo2DArray(Texture2D texture)
{
    Color[] colors1D = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
    texture.GetData(colors1D);
    Color[,] colors2D = new Color[texture.Width, texture.Height];
    for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
        {
            colors2D[x, y] = colors1D[x + y * texture.Width]; 
        }
    }
    return colors2D;
}
```

converting color to argb

```
public static string ToHex(this Color color, bool includeHash)
{
    string[] argb = {
        color.A.ToString("X2"),
        color.R.ToString("X2"),
        color.G.ToString("X2"),
        color.B.ToString("X2"),
    };
    return (includeHash ? "#" : string.Empty) + string.Join(string.Empty, argb);
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Does this method return a hexidecimal value color?

Comment: no, but you can strip (a)rgb values from color. `color.r.toString("x2")` will give you hexadecimal value or red color. so joining "r" "g" "b" will give you hexa code of color.

Answer (score 0):

You should first read the backbuffer (using `GraphicsDevice.GetBackBufferData()`) of the graphics device into a texture and then inspect the texture as described above.